# How can I disable graphic tablet pen buttons functions on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, tablet, wacom, xinput, graphics-tablet

I am a user of Ubuntu 22.04 and currently give online lessons.

For the lessons I use a tablet One by Wacom model CTL-672. My question is if there is a way to disable the stylus pen buttons? I mean that when I am using the stylus pen if I press any of the side buttons, it will not do anything, I don't need them.

Usually when I’m writing I press the buttons by mistake and it is annoying since they start to make additional lines in my drawing.

I tried to enter to Wacom control center that Ubuntu provides but when I entered I did not see any option like "disable" or "nothing". Here is a picture of the menu in my laptop with Ubuntu 22.04.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please add output of `xinput` command to your question.

Comment: How can I add output of xinput command to my question? I'm kind of new here.

Comment: You can [edit] your question.

Comment: at terminal type 'xinput'